# How to implement the same polygon to many .tiff images

Tags: qgis

So, the idea is that I have many .tiff files of the same place in different dates. I want to make a polygon that I need to implement it to all the .tiff files. The idea is that I will use polygon in order to put the boundaries and make a shapefile. I want to implement the same boundaries to all the rest .tiffs and get shapefiles of the others .tiff files (depicting the same place on different timestamps). I searched on google, I found nothing.... I use QGIS. Any ideas?

To ask differentely: I want to mark a region with a rectangle. This rectangle will have specific coordinates. UpperRight corner, UpperLeft corner, LowerLeft corner and LowerRight corner. I wlll keep what is inside this rectangle and I will delete the rest. So from UAV_1.tiff I will get a new rectangle.tiff that is the result of the inside of the rectangle. I need this rectangle with the specific coordinates to implement it to the other .tiffs. How can I do that?

Comment: You want a shapefile of the extent of the .tiff files? And you want the name of the polygon to be linked to the .tiff file?

Comment: Delete from the QGIS project or permanently from the disk?

Comment: I would suggest looking at the `clip by mask` tool within QGIS. Is that was you are wanting to do? But with every `.tif`? Is [this](https://freegistutorial.com/how-to-clip-raster-against-polygon-in-qgis/) what you want?

Comment: To ask differently I think you should use the [edit] button beneath your question to revise it.

Comment: I think a drawing of what you want to do would help. Are you asking how to make a polygon of all the tiff files common overlapping area?

Comment: @ BERA yes!! I have many images of the same place (captured at different timestamps) and I want the same shapefile of all of them.

Comment: @Binx: Can I implement it on all the 20 .tiff files that I have loaded to QGIS at once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it is using the [`clip by mask`](https://freegistutorial.com/how-to-clip-raster-against-polygon-in-qgis/) tool within QGIS. If you want to implement it on multiple .tiff files I would suggest using the `Run as Batch Process` within the clip by mask tool. It is located on the bottom left.

[image]

[image]

For a programmatical solution I would suggest using some sort of loop with either `gdal` or `rasterio`. Here are a couple of functions that I have used before. I've found the `gdal` function to be a little cleaner and faster for my situations. The `rasterio` function was created with the intent of having multiple polygons in different locations.

**GDAL**

```
def mask_ortho(ortho):
    OutTile = gdal.Warp('./QGIS_inputs/mask.tif',
                    ortho, 
                    cutlineDSName='./QGIS_inputs/Training.shp',
                    cropToCutline=True,
                    # dstNodata = 0,
                    creationOptions = ['COMPRESS=DEFLATE', 'PREDICTOR=2', 'ZLEVEL=9', 'NUM_THREADS=ALL_CPUS'])
    OutTile = None
```

**Rasterio**

```
def crop_ortho(poly, ortho_dir, output_dir):
    with rio.open(ortho_dir) as src:
        y = 0
        for each_roi in glob.glob(poly + '/*.shp'):
            shapefile = fiona.open(each_roi, 'r')
            shapes = [feature["geometry"] for feature in shapefile]
            try:
                out_image, out_transform = rio.mask.mask(src, shapes, crop=True)
                out_meta = src.meta
                out_meta.update({"driver": "GTiff",
                                 "height": out_image.shape[1],
                                 "width": out_image.shape[2],
                                 "transform": out_transform})
                output = output_dir + get_ortho_name(ortho) + '_' + str(y) + ".tif"
                with rio.open(output, "w", **out_meta) as dest:
                    dest.write(out_image)
                    dest.close()

                y = y + 1
                shapefile.close()
            except:
                pass

    src.close()
```